# error while sending email spring boot : Could not convert socket to TLS; Throws this exception randomly

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I am using Spring boot to send email at particular time of the day. I have achieved this using Spring scheduler. This part works fine. But while sending email, the application **randomly** throws a
Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

**The problem is it throws this exception randomly**.Other times the email is sent without any issue. 
Once it starts throwing the exception then i end up restarting the server. I cant do this once the application moves to Prod. I know the connection params and properties are correct since email are getting sent. Does any one have any idea why this happens.

Below are spring boot configuration that i have used

```
spring.mail.host=relay.xx.org
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=prabu.alias@mydomain.org
spring.mail.password=xxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=localhost
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.trust=*
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

The code that sends the email

```
    SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
    msg.setFrom(FROM_ADDRESS);
    msg.setTo(TO_ADDRESS);
    msg.setSubject("Test email ");
    msg.setText("This is a Test email generated at 5 PM." );
    javaMailSender.send(msg);
```

The exception trace below.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:446) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:321) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:310) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.ms.DmhThymeLeaf.utility.EmailScheduler.sendEmailActual(EmailScheduler.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.ms.DmhThymeLeaf.utility.EmailScheduler.cornJobSchedulerActual(EmailScheduler.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:515) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:435) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:620) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:547) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is the program running on the same machine every time?  If you're running in some sort of cloud or cluster environment and getting a different machine sometimes, there may be a machine with a bad JDK configuration.  Also, I assume your server is using a certificate with a public trust path, and that you didn't need to load a special certificate into your application to get it to work with your server.

Comment: It is not on the cloud or cluster environment. It is running on the same machine every time. There is no special certificate and I am not using any certificate as of now. But i intend to use a self-signed certificate later, since this application will be used internally.

Comment: I'm not sure but probably this line not work. spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.trust=*. Try this, mail.smtp.ssl.trust=* with spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true or place directly in properties object

Comment: If your server has a publicly signed and validated certificate, you should not need to set the trust property.  I don't know if Spring passes that property through to JavaMail.  But any problem with property setting would fail every time, so that doesn't explain what you're seeing.  Do you have a firewall or anti-virus program interposing on your communication with the server?  That might be the source of your problem.

Comment: I too thought it could be a firewall issue or something at the email server end, but if thats the case after the exception, the application should be able to send email later. but it keeps throwing the exception until i restart. so kind of not  sure its due to this. But for now if the exception happens at the sendEmail(), i am calling another method that will create a Properties object and set all the values and send email using java mail api. Here i create the object of MailSSLSocketFactory and setTrustAllHosts as true.

Comment: Also the exception happens if i keep sending emails every two minutes for a long time.(The application will not do this in Production). Is it related to memory issue.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel Thanks. Your suggestion worked. I have not had the issue after i modified the settings as you mentioned.

Comment: @prabu  nice : )